How to compare file_name versions?
I need help in below scenerio
current_file_version = "AvamarConsole-x86_64-19.9.0-78.rpm"

downloaded_file_version = "/usr/local/avamar/src/downloads/Console-RHEL7-X86_64/AvamarConsole-x86_64-19.9.0-78.rpm"

if current_file_version > downloaded_file_version
  #...(do upgrade)...
end

How to compare file_version (first two letter needs to compare ( only 19.9 ) ) in if condition ?
Need help in extracting version from file_version also.

I find your question unclear. First you claim that the current file version is AvamarConsole-x86_64-19.9.0-78.rpm, but then you are refer to the substrinct 19.9. I think you should define what exactly makes up a file version for you.

For simple comparing examples like '19.9.0' do something like this
if current_file_version.split('-')[-2] > downloaded_file_version.split('-')[-2]
  ...
end

Issues can be with comparing like '2.9.0' > '19.9.1'
Here you can transform version to current_file_version.split('-')[-2].split('.') and compare each digit separately

Write your condition as
current_file_version > File.basename(downloaded_file_version)
